# Pretérito perfecto + subjuntivo presente

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

En mi país (Uruguay) hay una propensión muy grande a cometer el error que ilustro en el siguiente ejemplo:

> Juan me pidió que vaya a su casa.

cuando debería ser

> Juan me pidió que fuera a su casa.

Leo y oigo tan, tan a menudo este error, que empiezo a dudar que lo sea. ¿Podrían confirmarme si es un error o no, y darme alguna referencia al respecto?

Comment: En Cuba sucede lo mismo...

Answer (score 1):

¿Es un error? No sé. Por lo menos está reconocido por la *Nueva Gramática* de la RAE.

> **24.1.1e** La tabla presentada en el §24.1.1a contiene cuatro tiempos del subjuntivo. En algunas variantes del español popular andino (y, en menor medida, del rioplatense) se neutralizan la primera y la tercera (con tiempos simples) y también la segunda y la cuarta (con tiempos compuestos). En estas variantes son comunes secuencias como *No llovió. Yo quería que llueva* (por *... que lloviera*), y también las correspondientes con tiempos compuestos: *Yo quería que haya llovido* (por *... que hubiera llovido*). Estos usos no han pasado a los registros formales.

Las formas de la tabla 24.1.1a a las que se refiere son:

- primera: presente (*No creo que Arturo **venga***)
- segunda: pretérito perfecto compuesto (*No creo que Arturo **haya venido***)
- tercera: pretérito imperfecto (*No creo que Arturo {**llegara** ~ **llegase**}*)
- cuarta: pretérito pluscuamperfecto (*No creo que Arturo {**hubiera** ~ **hubiese**} **llegado***)

Answer (score 1):

Al menos en mi ambiente (Argentina), la confusión entre tiempos presente y pasado del subjuntivo es común, y la forma incorrecta es tolerada en el habla informal.

En el caso que pones de ejemplo, además, la ambigüedad es mayor, porque, estrictamente hablando, las dos son aceptables con significados levemente distintos (y según el contexto, uno puede o no querer distinguir esos significados). Se trata de que, mientras la acción del verbo principal está en el pasado ("me pidió"), la acción pedida ("ir a su casa") puede referirse a un pasado finiquitado (con lo cual lo correcto sería "que fuera"), pero también puede ser un pedido vigente (en cuyo caso es correcto "que vaya").

Por ejemplo:

A. "Juan está internado en el hospital, nos pidió que lo **visitemos**" (el subjuntivo rige en el **presente**)

B. "Cuando Juan estuvo internado en el hospital, nos pidió que lo **visitáramos**" (en el **pasado**).

Estas son las versiones correctas, intercambiar los tiempos sería levemente incorrecto, pero aceptado.